# Dojo Store memory querying

Tags: memory, dojo, store

I have stored some data like below

```
var store = new Memory({
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: "one", prime: false },
        {id: 2, name: "two", even: true, prime: true},
        {id: 3, name: "three", prime: true},
        {id: 4, name: "four", even: true, prime: false},
        {id: 5, name: "five", prime: true}
    ]
});
```

I can query  all items where "prime" is true like below.

```
var results = store.query({ prime: true });
```

But how can I get the object whose "name" is either "one" or "two" without using foreach on query results like below

```
var results = store.query().forEach(function(each){
    if(each.name == "one" || each.name == "two") {
        console.log(each)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can perform query on multiple value for same field :

1. Without passing function using `regex`:

```js
require([
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory) {
  
  var store = new Memory({
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: "one", prime: false },
        {id: 2, name: "two", even: true, prime: true},
        {id: 3, name: "three", prime: true},
        {id: 4, name: "four", even: true, prime: false},
        {id: 5, name: "five", prime: true}
    ]
  });
  
  results = store.query({ name: new RegExp("one|two")});
  
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjore5sm/5/)

2. For complex querying pass a function that has a the search criteria to your query as parameter like below:

```js
require([
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory) {
  
  var store = new Memory({
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: "one", prime: false },
        {id: 2, name: "two", even: true, prime: true},
        {id: 3, name: "three", prime: true},
        {id: 4, name: "four", even: true, prime: false},
        {id: 5, name: "five", prime: true}
    ]
  });
  
  var results = store.query(
      function (element) {
        return element.name == "one" || element.name == "two";
      }
  );
  
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjore5sm/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to query without giving the function like  store.query({ name: "one" || name: "two" }). I just want to know is it possible to query like this without any function.